# SQL Comparing two dates after minipulation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query. Its purpose is to find what time products were ordered, check they match the conditions for the current day and then provide a list.

```
AND ( 
    (NameType <> 'Salad' AND completeDate < DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ' 10:30:00' ) ) 
    OR 
    (NameType = 'Salad' AND ( 
        ( DATE_FORMAT( completeDate , '%h:%i:%s' ) <= '14:00:00' ) 
            AND DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(completeDate,'%Y-(%m)-%d'), INTERVAL +1 DAY) < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        )
    )
    OR
    (NameType = 'Salad' AND ( 
        ( DATE_FORMAT( completeDate , '%h:%i:%s' ) > '14:00:00' )   
            AND DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(completeDate,'%Y-(%m)-%d'), INTERVAL +2 DAY) < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        )
    )
)
```

The logic:

`If a Bagel is ordered before 10:30 it will arrive that day. If not it will arrive the next.`

`If a Salad is ordered before 14:00 it will arrive the next day. If after this, it will arrive in two working days.` (yeah seems crazy me to me!)

So with a current Date of, `2015-05-06`

And a table as such;

```
 |ID|NameType|  completeDate     |
 |1 |Salad   |2015-05-05 13:00:00|
 |2 |Salad   |2015-05-04 19:00:00|
 |3 |Bagel   |2015-05-05 08:00:00|
 |4 |Bagel   |2015-05-05 11:00:00|
```

Should output,

```
 |ID|NameType|  completeDate     |
 |1 |Salad   |2015-05-05 13:00:00|
 |3 |Bagel   |2015-05-05 08:00:00|
```

However its ommiting the salad/ID 1!

Is this somethign todo with how im comparing the dates? Wondering if casting them to a string might help.

Comment: doh, dont know why that was in there. Any ideas whats going wrong here @Tanner?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar enough with mysql to be able to help, I just recognised that the functions you were using weren't sql-server functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to how I compared the two strings.

Casting them as `DATE` resolved the issue.

```
AND ( 
    (NameType <> 'Salad' AND completeDate < DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ' 10:30:00' ) ) 
    OR 
    (NameType = 'Salad' AND ( 
        ( DATE_FORMAT( completeDate , '%H:%i:%s' ) <= '14:00:00' ) 
            AND CAST(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(completeDate,'%Y-(%m)-%d'), INTERVAL +1 DAY) AS DATE) <= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE)
        )
    )
    OR
    (NameType = 'Salad' AND ( 
        ( DATE_FORMAT( completeDate , '%H:%i:%s' ) > '14:00:00' )   
            AND CAST(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(completeDate,'%Y-(%m)-%d'), INTERVAL +2 DAY) AS DATE) <= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re using 24 hour military time in `'14:00:00'`, but 12 hour regular time with %h in `'%h:%i:%s'` (so 1:30pm would come out as `'01:30:00'`). Formatting like this instead may help:

```
'%H:%i:%s'
```

Comment: thanks for the comment Honore, have updated the SQL but its stil returning just the bagel. Struggling to see what else could be going wrong? I am comparing my dates correctly?

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure if operators like less than officially support string comparison.  You could try using STRCMP instead of <, or using STR_TO_DATE to convert `'14:00:00'` (though you may have to add the current day/month/year into your string first).

Comment: I now beleive its because I'm attempting to compare a date with a string. I believe dates are only valid if they are appended with the time. Could be wrong but will have a look

Comment: thanks for your help @Honore, you was correct regarding the comparitors. Casting to DATE allowed me to compare